Are there any programming languages based on the method of analytic tableaux, aside from Fitting's Proflog?
The method of analytic tableaux [0] describes a process by which logical formulae, particularly of first order logic, can be determined to be valid or invalid. From the Wikipedia entry:

A tableau calculus is simply a set of rules that prescribes how a tableau can be modified. A proof procedure is a method for actually finding a proof (if one exists). In other words, a tableau calculus is a set of rules, while a proof procedure is a policy of application of these rules.

As a proof procedure, aka a proof search algorithm, the method of analytic tableaux should be able to be made executable, as the basis of operation of a logic programming language, contra the more common SLD resolution [1] (with depth first search) of Prolog. Indeed, at least one such language has been described: Proflog [2], by Melvin Fitting.
However, Fitting does not provide an implementation, nor has my research thus far found any subsequent work on this type of programming language, with or without an implementation.
Therefore: are there any programming languages (either proposed, or, of especial interest, implemented) that are based on the method of analytic tableaux?
Because of the equivalence between analytic tableaux and sequent systems, languages based on the latter might also qualify, but I am particularly interested, for this question, on the former.
[0] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution
[2] (Paywall) https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00881954
